# NFC Bluetooth handover - WITHOUT user confirmation

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, out-of-band

I wrote an NDEF message in an NFC tag according to NFC Forum specification fo doing a Bluetooth handover. I am facing 2 issues:

1. Bluetooth is enabled when I tap the tag with my phone but it gets disabled after a very short period (less than a minute).
2. I want the pairing to happen without any confirmation. But in my case it is asking for confirmation for pairing.

I have 3 records in my NDEF message:

1. a record of type "HS",
2. a record of type "AC", and
3. an OOB data record (with EIR data blank).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Any help to my above issues..?

Comment: Did you ever fix this is issue? I am facing the same issues

Comment: no, unfortunately i could not fix this. still trying. if you come across any solution pls share with me as well.